# Is there a way to automate the [Y/N] prompts when installing packages from a linux script

Tags: bash, terminal, prompt

I have a script that installs few apps that require the user to type Y about 5 times during the script.  Is it possible to automate or bypass the Y so the script just runs through without the need for any user interaction?

Comment: Many installation scripts have an option to assume "yes" answers to questions. Have you checked whether this one does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pipe `yes` to it.

```
yes | <command here>
```

Comment: OK, well for example these lines are in my script:`apt-get update
sleep 4
apt-get install openssh-server
sleep 2
apt-get install php5 
sleep 2
apt-get install libpcsclite1
sleep 2
apt-get install libpcsclite-dev
sleep 2
apt-get install openssl
sleep 2
apt-get install libssl-dev
sleep 2
apt-get install pcscd
sleep 2
apt-get install pcsc-tools`  There are about 5 prompts during these installs for user input, how would I incorperate your answer into my script?  Thankyou

Comment: Also, is there a way to move to the next line when commenting on stackoverflow?  My above post looks very messy because I dont know how to add line breaks to my comments..

Comment: Please Ignore my comment about incorperate your answer into my script, I now understand and have it working perfectly..  Thankyou for your help..